# Migrated WordPress Site and Now Theme Isn't Loading WordPress Functions

Tags: php, wordpress

Just migrated a website from local machine to staging server.

Weirdly, the theme isn't loading the functions even though the stack trace looks correct:

```
[15-Dec-2017 00:22:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function of_get_option() in /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/header.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/template.php(555): require_once()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/template.php(514): load_template('/var/www/html/a...', true)
#2 /var/www/html/wp-includes/general-template.php(45): locate_template(Array, true)
#3 /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/index.php(1): get_header()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(75): include('/var/www/html/a...')
#5 /var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php(16): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#6 /var/www/html/index.php(17): require('/var/www/html/w...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/header.php on line 37
```

I am in a hurry so I have tried just copying a copy of the of `_get_option` function into the file which got rid of the error.

But then up popped another one in it's place.

```
[15-Dec-2017 00:29:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(../wp-includes\option.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/header.php on line 33
[15-Dec-2017 00:29:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '../wp-includes\option.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/header.php on line 33
[15-Dec-2017 00:29:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function WC() in /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/header.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/template.php(555): require_once()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/template.php(514): load_template('/var/www/html/a...', true)
#2 /var/www/html/wp-includes/general-template.php(45): locate_template(Array, true)
#3 /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/index.php(1): get_header()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(75): include('/var/www/html/a...')
#5 /var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php(16): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#6 /var/www/html/index.php(17): require('/var/www/html/w...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/assets/themes/underscore/header.php on line 79
```

Anyone got any clue why this is?

Comment: I wonder if there are deactivated plugins that your theme is relying on? `WC()` is Woocommerce, I'm quite sure. Go to the plugins page and make sure they're all there, too. Sometimes plugins go dark during a migration.

Comment: I am unable to login at present but thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`themes/underscore/header.php` has an incorrect reference to another file, this looks likely to be a problem `/wp-includes\option.php`

Comment: The same file works perfectly locally which is baffling, think I will just wipe and try a different migration. Thanks for your help.

Comment: but is the directory structure the same?

Comment: Can't be sure. I've deleted it in order to try a different backup. Thanks for your suggestions.